# Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.226.0>) failed to connect:

Tags: phoenix-framework

I've just started learning Phoenix and I ran into the following error after typing `mix phoenix.server`:

`[error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.226.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (localhost:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused`

However, the website is running perfectly when I run localhost:400

Comment: That error means either PostgreSQL is not running or it's running on a port other than 5432. The pages of your app that do not use the database will still work. Have you installed PostgreSQL and is it running on port 5432?

Comment: @Dogbert after starting postgresql I ran into another error: `[error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.227.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 3D000 (invalid_catalog_name): database "blog_dev" does not exist`

Comment: You need to run `mix ecto.create` - this will create the database on your postgres server now that it's running. Check out http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/ecto-models for more information